# Trying to use the strip() function but running to a error

Tags: python

I have a text file like this, the strings represent file paths and integers represents class type and they are separated by a space.

```
FEA/1048_IEO_FEA_MD.mp4  3

FEA/1029_IWW_FEA_XX.mp4  3

FEA/1002_WSI_FEA_XX.mp4  3

FEA/1001_IWW_FEA_XX.mp4  3
```

In my code, I'd like to assign paths and labels to different variable and append them to a list,

```
def get_clip_list(self, cliplist_file):
    
    datalist = list(open(cliplist_file, 'r'))
    clips_with_label = []
    for data in datalist:
        path, label = data.strip('\n').split(' ')[0], int(data.strip('\n').split(' ')[1])
        clips_with_label.append({'path': path, 'label': label})
    return clips_with_label
```

My error is "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' ". I am not sure what this means, All my labels are integers. Help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Its working good for, as I saved the input in txt file. O/P: `[{'path': 'FEA/1048_IEO_FEA_MD.mp4', 'label': 3},
 {'path': 'FEA/1029_IWW_FEA_XX.mp4', 'label': 3},
 {'path': 'FEA/1002_WSI_FEA_XX.mp4', 'label': 3},
 {'path': 'FEA/1001_IWW_FEA_XX.mp4', 'label': 3}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are empty lines between data lines, and the seperation is two spaces instead of one. When you turn the file into a `list`, the empty lines are turned into `'\n'`'s. They cannot be turned into `int`s. The two spaces when `split` will contain empty strings. Just remove the blank lines and change the spaces into one and you'll be fine.

Or, if that's not an option, you can add a blank line mechanism and change the `split` to any whitespace. For example, change your code to:

```
def get_clip_list(cliplist_file):
    datalist = list(open(cliplist_file, 'r'))
    clips_with_label = []
    for data in datalist:
        if data == '\n':
            continue
        path, label = data.split()[0], int(data.split()[1])
        clips_with_label.append({'path': path, 'label': label})
    return clips_with_label
```

The `if` statement detects the empty lines and the `split` without any arguments splits with any whitespace.

P.S.: I removed your `strip('\n')` because `int` can turn strings with `'\n'` into integers well.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> 'FEA/1048_IEO_FEA_MD.mp4  3'.strip('\n').split(' ')
['FEA/1048_IEO_FEA_MD.mp4', '', '3']
```

`int('')` will raise a `ValueError`. Use:

```
>>> 'FEA/1048_IEO_FEA_MD.mp4  3'.strip('\n').split()
['FEA/1048_IEO_FEA_MD.mp4', '3']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you're splitting on actual space. [From the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

> If *sep* is given, consecutive delimiters are not grouped together and
> **are deemed to delimit empty strings** (for example, `'1,,2'.split(',')`
> returns `['1', '', '2']`).

Also:

> If *sep* is not specified or is `None`, a different splitting algorithm is
> applied: **runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single
> separator**, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start
> or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace.

<sup>* Emphasis mine</sup>

So you simply need to use `split()` instead of `split(' ')`.

---

A few other notes on your code:

- There is no need at all to `strip` the lines because the `int()` constructor knows how to handle the new-line characters. For example: `int("   5  \n") == 5`.
- You are calling the `split` twice which is wasteful. Call it once, and [unpack the result](https://treyhunner.com/2018/03/tuple-unpacking-improves-python-code-readability/).
- You will also need to skip the empty lines to avoid further errors. For this, you *can* use `strip`.

A revised version of your code:

```py
def get_clip_list(self, cliplist_file):
    clips_with_label = []

    with open(cliplist_file) as file:
        for line in file:
            if line.strip():
                path, label = line.split()
                clips_with_label.append({'path': path, 'label': int(label)})
    return clips_with_label
```